# Ionic 3 - Want to convert array of object to array of strings in controller

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

In Ionic 3, I am fetching an array of objects in the controller. But it is not useful for me. So I want to convert array of objects to array of strings.. I am getting following data in controller.

```
   this.users = [{"id":1,"name":"US"},{"id":2,"name":"UK"}]
```

But I want the result below:

```
    this.users = ["US", "UK"];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that in a single line like this:

```
this.users = this.users.map(user => user.name);
```

Comment: Its Working...Sir

Comment: Glad to hear that @SanchitMahajan :)